# Tagging of query tuning questions

Tags: discussion, tagging

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/query-tuning-help) made me think of a new tag for 'query-optimization' or 'query-tuning'. However it was pointed out that this type of tag might be a duplicate for other SE sites. To me, it seems 'query' is too general and if we're going to allow questions of that nature (and imo, we should; but that's another topic I guess) we should be more specific on the purpose of the question. Alternatively, it could be tagged as 'query' and 'optimization'.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I think query tuning *can* be OK, if it is sufficiently advanced / interesting for a crowd of dbas.

See:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/

Comment: So the question is "is the tag appropriate" not "is the class of question appropriate" ~ Alternately, what tag would be appropriate? `query-tuning` vs `tuning` vs `optimization`

Comment: I would vote for **query-tuning** is shorter.